# array_splice removing more than one item

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following method:

```
public function selectFinal(){
    $db = new Database();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $key_id = mt_rand(0, count($this->candidates) - 1);
        $itm    = $this->candidates[$key_id];
        $host   = $itm["host"];
        $item   = $itm["item"];
        $db->query("insert ignore into trends (trend_id, host, item) values (?, ?, ?)", array($this->nextId, $host, $item));
        array_splice($this->candidates, $key_id, -1);
        print_r($this->candidates);
        $this->nextId++;
    }
}
```

For the `print_r()` I am getting this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => IytNBm8WA1c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => kffacxfA7G4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => kXYiU_JCYtU
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => 7AVHXe-ol-s
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => qkM6RJf15cg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => IytNBm8WA1c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => qkM6RJf15cg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => qkM6RJf15cg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => qkM6RJf15cg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.youtube.com
            [item] => qkM6RJf15cg
        )

)
```

The array will start with 5 or more items in it. What I would like to do is select a random item from the array and insert it into the database then remove it from the array. I want to do this 5 times to get 5 random items from the array. But for some reason it is selecting 1 then removing 3 items from the array, and I am not sure why (shown in the second section of code).

**Edit: Final Working Result**

```
public function selectFinal(){
    $db = new Database();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $key_id = mt_rand(0, count($this->candidates) - 1);
        $itm    = array_values(array_merge([$this->nextId], array_splice($this->candidates, $key_id, 1)[0]));
        $db->query("insert ignore into trends (trend_id, host, item) values (?, ?, ?)", $itm);
        $this->nextId++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more *safe* in splicing the element out and use that outtake. In case you made an error with that, you notice by not having correct values to store. This will make you more aware of a potential problem:

```
$key_id = mt_rand(0, count($this->candidates) - 1);
$itm = array_splice($this->candidates, $key_id, -1);
var_dump($itm);
```

See? You then can better pin-point the problem, e.g. -1 is not 1. See http://php.net/array_splice

```
public function selectFinal() {
    $db = $this->db;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
    {
        $key_id = mt_rand(0, count($this->candidates) - 1);
        $values = array_merge(
            [$this->nextId], array_splice($this->candidates, $key_id, 1)
                                                                     ###
        );

        print_r($this->candidates);

        $db->query(
            "insert ignore into trends (trend_id, host, item) values (?, ?, ?)", 
            array_values($values)
        );

        $this->nextId++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect that works great! and using `1` instead of `-1` helped too!

Comment: Yes that was a little hint. I just edited again, a code-example leaving some more hints: Do not make new Database() per each method call, store it with a private member. Also it shows a little trick to create the array values which might work in your case to make the database query easier to invoke.

Comment: `$values` equals `Array
(
    [0] => 201305042040
)` when I do it like that.

Comment: Yes, my fault, the merging does not work there. It's more `array_merge([$this->nextId], array_splice($this->candidates, $key_id, 1))`. No clue if this is worth.

Comment: PDO yells at me doing this, so I am just going to do that, and then grab the variables individually. I think it is because two of the values have string keys: `host` and `item`

Comment: also you need to do `[0]` after the `array_splice` to get the first sub array: `array_merge([$this->nextId], array_splice($this->candidates, $key_id, 1)[0])`

Comment: yeah, that can be. It was just a quick idea I had and I feared PDO might do that (`array_values` could come to a rescue then). // `[0]` -> hence the `array_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want delete a array item of a specific key you can use -

```
unset($this->candidates[$key_id])
```

Comment: Which will leave a hole in the key-space resulting in (potential) errors in further iterations. `array_splice()` removes these gaps by not preserving numeric keys.

Comment: Yes it will if he further try to iterate the same array, but here in the code he is not iterating using the key

Comment: There is further, at least 4 times further because of 5 iterations: *"I want to do this 5 times to get 5 random items from the array."*